# MySQL "Sending Data" state took so long

Tags: mysql

I run a query yesterday directly on my Phpmyadmin of my server. This query is working on my localhost and I want to test if it will also work on the old data on my server. Here's the query;

```
SELECT a.*, SUM(d.due_to_supplier) AS due_to_supplier, SUM(d.due_to_office) AS due_to_office, SUM(d.due_to_outlet) AS due_to_outlet, SUM(d.due_to_seller) AS due_to_seller, SUM(d.credit_card) AS credit_card, b.description, c.FirstName FROM sales_entry_summary a, sales_products b , user_account c , sales_entry d WHERE a.product_id = b.product_id AND a.ses_id = d.ses_id AND a.seller_id = c.UserID AND a.sales_date BETWEEN '2019-09-05' AND '2019-09-05' AND (c.FirstName LIKE '%%' OR a.particulars LIKE '%%' OR a.reloc LIKE '%%' OR a.lead_name LIKE '%%') AND a.product_id IN (2) OR a.psub_id IN (2,6,103) GROUP BY a.ses_id
```

My phpmyadmin just keep loading and I know something is wrong. I open another tab of phpmyadmin and try to run other query and it worked, then I tried to run the same query and phpmyadmin keeps on getting hanged. So I closed my phpmyadmin hoping that it will kill my SQL requests. However upon checking on my server usage, MySQL is taking so much CPU usage. Which I suspect that it was the hanged query I run. I tried checking on MySQL Process list and I found this;

[MySQL Processlist Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XblK.png)

There's the query I executed multiple time and it's still on Sending data state after a long time.

How can I stop this query from executing? And why did this happen? My query is working fine on my localhost.

Comment: Have you tried to simply restart the MySQL service?

Comment: Yes I tried and it gone away. However, whenever I execute this script the same issue occurs.

Comment: You are going to have to debug the query in that case.